# There is no "used in actions" in Media-type

Tags: zabbix

I 'm usiing zabbix 3.4

I want to know how to link Action with media-type.

I tried all ways i knew but it was useless.

Below is the steps i did.
1. Create a media-type
2. Create a user for newly created media-type.
3. Create Action.
3.1 Add Operations on the acknowledgement operations tab.
3.3 New - Send message to users.

==> But there is no "used in actions" in the Media-type lists.

If someone has solution , let me know it.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That column is populated for media types that are [used directly](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/web_interface/frontend_sections/administration/mediatypes) in actions - that is, explicitly selected in the dropdown in action properties.

By default actions do not limit to any media types and all media types will be used as per the user media entries and various filters.

Comment: I read that document about media type. But what i wonder is that it doesn't work as i expected. There is no special configuration to do as i know. 
Moreover, Problem operation and recovery operation worked well.